# AmazonS3 SDK: Access denied when Listing Objects

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm trying to list the objects from a bucket but keep getting blocked when I try to list the objects in the bucket.

However all `s3.list*` commands fail with the below error. How do I return a list of files from a folder within a bucket?

**Code**

```
LOGGER.info("tomorrowBucket: [{}]", tomorrowBucket);
if (s3.doesBucketExistV2(tomorrowBucket)) {
    LOGGER.info("made it");
    LOGGER.info("probably gonna fail");
    for (S3ObjectSummary summary : S3Objects.inBucket(s3, tomorrowBucket)) {
         LOGGER.info(" * " + summary.getKey() + "  " + "(size = " + summary.getSize() + ")");
     }
     LOGGER.info("made it past");
}
```

**Logs**

```
  tomorrowBucket: [20200311]
 - made it
 - probably gonna fail
```

**Error**

```
     com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Failed to parse XML document with handler class com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser$ListObjectsV2Handler
...
    Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; Premature end of file.
```

Comment: Buckets don't contain other buckets. Or are you using the term 'bucket' to mean something other than an S3 bucket?

Comment: @jarmod What I meant was folders within a bucket

Comment: @jarmod I've tried moving to `listObjects` and I'm getting a `Failed to parse XML Document with handler...` error

Comment: Are you using an up to date version of the AWS SDK for Java, and calling the AmazonS3Client's `listObjectsV2(String bucketName)` method?

Comment: @jarmod I'm using sdk 1.11.740 and I've updated the code above accordingly, using (and failing on) the `listObjectsV2`

Comment: Do your AWS credentials have ListBucket permission on the S3 bucket? Also, be sure you are using `listObjectsV2` against a bucket name (and only a bucket name). You can't use it against folders (you need to use `withPrefix()` for that).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209448/discussion-between-pt-c-and-jarmod).

Comment: You say "How do I return a list of files from a folder within a bucket?", S3 buckets don't actually have folders. If you create an object with a "/" in its name, then the AWS UI will make it look like an object in a folder, but the folder doesn't actually exist, so trying to get a list of files from the folder isn't what you can exactly do. If you just mean you want a list of all objects in a bucket, then that's OK, that should work fine - not sure why you are getting that error, but I suspect it's because tomorrowBucket isn't actually a bucket.

Comment: @BillShubert that's the problem, it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I was specifying the bucket in the endpoint configuration as opposed to pointing directly to the tenant:

**Incorrect**

```
hs3Client.setEndpoint("bucketname.europe.hcp.example.com");
```

**Correct**

```
// Set up the service point to be the tenant in HCP.
hs3Client.setEndpoint("europe.hcp.example.com");
```